# Very Simple clock in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to use setInterval function in react to repeatedly render a function in react . Please provide a very simple example . I am using Node js local environment. Here I am trying for a [simple clock given in react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) (but mine file structure is different). I don't know about didMount etc.. Just starting.

**Below is my App.jsx**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {

good(){
  {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
}
   render() {
      return (
         <p>{setInterval(()=>this.good(),500)}</p>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';


  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="app"></div>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My folder structure is like below

[image: folder structure]

Comment: I suggest you to read more about React components, state and props as these are fundamental parts for which you have chosen to use React in first place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read more about React components, state and props as these are fundamental parts for which you have chosen to use React in first place. Basic steps would be:

- Store time as state of your component.
- Start ticking functionality as soon as your component loads (that is what **componentDidMount** does - it's triggered when component loads in page)
- On each tick use **setState** to change time value (setState triggers render)

If you follow these steps you would achieve similar result to example from [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) site, and this is how it should really be done (if you really want to do it in React design)